# Where Mysql procurar por palavra completa

Tags: mysql, sql, where

Eu tenho um banco de dados e gostaria de saber como eu faço pra procurar pelo dado digitando o resultado completo usando where

Exemplo:

```
ID  NOME  CODIGOS
1  | Joao   | 9714,51,100
2  | Maria  | 50,9714,88100
```

Ai queria fazer que retornasse um where pesquisando por CODIGOS

Pesquisa: 100

Mostrar: Joao

Pesquisa: 9714

Mostrar: Joao, Maria

Eu fiz assim:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE codigo like '%100%'
```

Porém o 100 pesquisado ta mostrando todos os resultados que tem 100, então retorna 88100 e 100

O que posso estar fazendo?

Comment: se uma resposta lhe serviu então marque-a como aceita, veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/6985#6985

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIND_IN_SET - Serve para localizar dados em um campo da tabela que tenha valores separados por vírgula.

```
SELECT * FROM nomeTabela WHERE FIND_IN_SET('valorBuscado', nomeColuna);
```

Exemplo tabela usada:

[image: tabela]

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE FIND_IN_SET(100, codigo);
```

Resultado

[image: resultado select]

Comment: Nice! Vai um teste ai para complementar.... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9760cf/14

Comment: Faltou verificar se o resultado de `FIND_IN_SET` e maior que 0 (zero), pois essa função apenas retorna o indice da string *9714* na string de valores separados por virgula. Ficaria `where FIND_IN_SET('9714', nomeColuna) > 0;`

Comment: Funcionou certinho, obg.. não conhecia essa função find_in_set

Comment: @RodrigoK.B não é necessário, se o resultado for `0` ele funcionará como o `false` e se for diferente funcionará como o `true`.

Comment: @LucasMoraes, já que resolveu, marca a resposta como aceita ;)